# How to have each turtle share the same links as their link-neighbors

Tags: netlogo

I've been trying to write a model where turtles create links with a certain number of other turtles, and for those turtles to create links with the link-neighbors of the turtle that linked to it. Right now, I can get turtles to create links with other turtles, but they don't share the same link-neighbors. I want to end up with little sub-groups of turtles of a certain group size. However, at the moment I can only tell turtles to create a certain number of links, but they don't end up in sub-groups because their link-neighbors don't necessarily share the same link-neighbors. I thought I could ask each turtle to ask their link-neighbors to create-link-with [link-neighbors] of myself. I think this would work, except I get an error saying a turtle can't link with itself. I've tried to change the code so it says to a turtle ask link-neighbors [create-link-with [link-neighbors] of myself with [who != self]], but this doesn't work either.

Here is some of my code:

```
;group size is 1 + (count link-neighbors) 
;preferred-size is a slider, used to alter what group size I want turtles to be in

 ask turtles 
   [if (preferred-size > group-size) and (any? other turtles in-radius 1 with [preferred-size > group-size])
   [create-link-with one-of other turtles in-radius 1 with [preferred-size > group-size] 

   ask link-neighbors
   [create-links-with [link-neighbors] of myself]
   ]
```

Also, is there a term like link-neighbors but referring to all the turtles on a string of connections?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close! All you need is [`other`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other):

```
create-links-with other [ link-neighbors ] of myself
```

You cannot compare `who` to `self`: `who` is a number and `self` is a turtle. And in the context of `with [ who != self ]]`, they would always be variables of the same turtle. In any case, it's usually better to avoid dealing with `who` numbers anyway: there's almost always a better way to do things.

> is there a term like link-neighbors but referring to all the turtles on a string of connections?

I'm not entirely sure that's what you mean, but maybe [`nw:turtles-on-path-to`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#path-to-turtles-on-path-to-weighted-path-to-turtles-on-weighted-path-to)? Or perhaps you will find some other useful thing in the [`nw` extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! That makes sense. I'm not sure if the nw:turtles-on-path-to is what I was looking for, but I may not need it now anyway.